# Re sequence transactions in database table

Tags: sql, teradata

I've got some data in a Teradata database that needs to have its transaction sequence re-sequenced so that the transactions show up like this:

```
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|Tx_Seq|Tx_Date  |O/Bal|Qty |C/Bal|
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |1/08/2012|0    |500 |500  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |2/08/2012|500  |-100|400  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |3/08/2012|400  |250 |650  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|2     |3/08/2012|650  |100 |750  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|3     |3/08/2012|750  |-400|350  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|4     |3/08/2012|350  |-100|250  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |4/08/2012|250  |200 |450  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |5/08/2012|450  |100 |550  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
```

It currently looks like this:

```
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|Tx_Seq|Tx_Date  |O/Bal|Qty |C/Bal|
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |1/08/2012|0    |500 |500  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |2/08/2012|500  |-100|400  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|3     |3/08/2012|400  |250 |650  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|2     |3/08/2012|650  |100 |750  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|4     |3/08/2012|750  |-400|350  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |3/08/2012|350  |-100|250  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |4/08/2012|250  |200 |450  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
|1     |5/08/2012|450  |100 |550  |
+------+---------+-----+----+-----+
```

Note that the tx_seq is out of normal ordering for o/Bal for 3/08/2012 . I've tried analytical functions such as  ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING as means to re-sequence but could not make it work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could the same balance be produced multiple times in a single day? If so, I don't see how you can correct the `Tx_Seq` values in a deterministic fashion, based purely on the columns you've shown.

Comment: Damien the same obal and cbal could happen as its possible to stock out. The table is over 10 million records with the sequence number not in sequence for opening balance for transactions for the same day. Sometimes there may be only two transactions on the same day, sometimes thousands.

Comment: So, if on 3/08/2012 the balance was at 400 at three different time (the start value as shown in your sample and two more I've just made up) that means that there are two sequences of transactions on that day that are `400->other value->other value->...->400`. There's no way (given the data you've shown) to know which of those two sequences came first. And if those two sequences share any other common balance values, then more permutations are possible.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you I could not find any permutations to make the sequence number reflect the correct ordering of o/bal. Hence my question to the world. My fall back strategy will be to update the obal and cbal to reflect the sequence number. This should give the same cbal on after completion of all transactions of the day and therefore carry the right carry forward balance for the subsequent days.